# How to correct display last line of justified paragraph Docx4j

Tags: java, docx4j

I have a paragraph Justified with a PPr object. All paragraph is justified but the last line not.

I know that it's necessary use a LineBreak after last line to give the correct justification. I try with PPr with set a JC object but doesn't work

```
   PPr bothPPr = factory.createPPr();
   Jc justified = factory.createJc();
   bothPPr.setJc(justified);
   P p = factory.createP();
   R r = factory.createR();
   Text t = factory.createText();
   t.setValue("Long text here...");
   r.getContent().add(t);
   r.getContent().add(factory.createBr());
   p.getContent().add(r);
   p.setPPr(bothPPr);
```

All text is correctly justified, but last line isn't.

My actual last justified line:

```
This       is         my         last         line
```

But I want:

```
This is my last line
```

After I open my generate docx file, I can see the wrong justification. But if I press Enter Button at the end of line, the justification works good.

Comment: Can you produce and attach a docx in Word which looks how you want?

Comment: This is my actually result : [Screenshot](https://ibb.co/zSQrPSX). 

 I insert a paragraph with PPr set. This PPr contain a Jc object with JcEnumeration.BOTH </br> After that I insert a break line and I  think it's the problem: indeed I try to create an empty paragraph to create space between 2 paragraph and "Last line" spacing of first paragraph works good. So I think I found the solution using a new empty paragraph?

Comment: Yes I think the result you originally got is what you'd expect

Answer (score 0):

It turns out there is actually an obscure compat setting  which will give the behaviour you want.  From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2010/cc844177%28v%3Doffice.14%29

> [ISO/IEC 29500-1 1st Edition]
>
> 17.15.3.5 doNotExpandShiftReturn (Don't Justify Lines Ending in Soft Line Break)
>
> This element specifies whether applications should fully justify the
>   contents of incomplete lines which end in a soft line break when the
>   parent paragraph is fully justified using the jc element (§17.3.1.13).
>
> Typically, applications shall fully justify all lines in a paragraph
>   when that setting is specified using the jc element except for the
>   last line in the paragraph (the line ending with the paragraph mark).
>   This element, when present with a val attribute value of true (or
>   equivalent), specifies that any line which ends in a soft line break
>   shall also not be fully justified when the paragraph specifies that
>   setting.